# Sum to Product Identities

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When deriving the Sum to Product Identities for  Sine and Cosine of  (a + b) (a - b) we take  X= (a + b) and Y = (a - b) and then ÷  by 2 when adding X + Y and  X - Y. Is this because we have two values of a and b? When we are given say Sine of 105 degrees and 15 degrees we just add them and then take the difference rather than (a + b) + (a - b) and (a + b) - (a - b). We still divide by 2. Why is this?

Comment: If you just write it out, you can see that $(X+Y)/2 = a$ and $(X-Y)/2 = b$.  If that doesn't answer your question, can you add more context?  I'm not sure what you're really asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's because $\begin{align*}a-b&=x\\ a+b&=y\end{align*}$ so adding the two equations yields $2a=x+y\to a=\frac{x+y}{2}$ the same applies with $y$

Comment: Thanks. I saw a video on You Tube and I posted my question which stated what you said. Most of the videos tell the students to make the substitution but give no explanation why. Thanks for your response

Comment: Thanks. I saw a video on You Tube after I posted my question which stated what you said. Most of the videos tell the students to make the substitution but give no explanation why. Thank for your response